# Terminal has gone weird after screen sharing

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I used screen sharing on my Macbook Pro to remote control my friend's iMac.

Unfortunately, now my Terminal now says:

```
kellys-iphone-2:~ James$
```

Why is it now saying this all of a sudden? Where has `kellys-iphone-2` come from? Should I be worried?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know kelly?

Comment: Nope, not at all lol

Comment: Have you simply tried rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

The default prompt in Mac OS X is derived from `System Preferences` -> `Sharing` -> `Computer Name`. If that is set correctly and you still see `kellys-iphone` in new terminal prompts, your terminal environment variable `PS1` has been set in either `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or some other local file.

You can check which files set PS1 like so: `grep PS1 ~/.*`

Side note: If you see a line like this:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

which just means "if this is not an interactive shell, disregard the rest of this file" - so that's not the droids you're looking for.

That should reveal a file that has a line akin to this:

```
export PS1="\u@\h\w$ "
```

Or, if I'm right:

```
export PS1="kellys-iphone-2:\w "
```

Edit that file/line to reflect what you really want. [More info about custom prompts in OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/)

Comment: What would it have been originally?

Comment: Also, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` don't have PS1 set at all... and grep hasn't helped me at all

Comment: Grep returned this: http://pastebin.com/KNf55ufV

Comment: What's the output from the following; `uname -a; hostname; echo $PS1`?

Comment: It's going to be your hostname, look under system pref, as the first part says.

Comment: @Jan http://pastebin.com/gGzEZK3k

Comment: @demure My computer name under sharing is correct as it should be.

Comment: Just found out my NetBios name is KELLYS-IPHONE-2 as well, every time I change it, it reverts back... How the hell is this even happening?

Comment: Next to "computer name", under sys pref -> sharing, is a button marked "Edit...". Click it, and verify what the local host name is. (computer name, and local host name are different settings)

Comment: My Mac seems to have fixed it itself 0_o

Comment: At work, our DHCP server will sometimes "recycle" old names for IPs.  The "kellys-iphone-2" name is 99% certainly coming from somewhere similar.

Comment: It seemed to be fixed as soon as I left work with my Mac so you could be right

Answer (score 0):

First do not panic :)

If you want to change that just do flowing:

System preferences > Sharing >Edit

Here you will see the kellys-iphone-2

Just change it to what you like :)
[image]

Comment: It doesn't say kellys-iphone-2...

Comment: And my Mac seems to have fixed itself 0_o