# Odd bug in iTerm — Why is my name wrong?

Tags: terminal, iterm

[image]

I opened up iterm and it says "jessica-s-phone" I'm not sure what the term for that is. I checked my profile and it isn't there.

Comment: This doesn't look like an iTerm issue. Someone posted something like this a while ago. Is your computer connected to a WiFi hotspot, by any chance? Also, have you edited .bash_profile (PS1 variable)?

Comment: Found something: [Terminal has gone weird after screen sharing](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92513/terminal-has-gone-weird-after-screen-sharing) So, have you enabled screen sharing?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the name of your computer. If you go to sharing in the system preferences you should see "Computer Name" there.

Comment: That's one of the things I thought it might be, however my PC is still labeled Patrick's Macbook.